# PostGIS, creating spatial index on box2d column failes

Tags: postgis, extents, spatial-index

I would like to store bounding boxes in a column of my table. Thus I wanted to use the box2d data-type for that column. However it seems like I can't create an index on that column. Here is my simplified SQL code:

```
    CREATE TABLE "rm"."test" (
      "id" serial PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
      "bbox" box2d
    );
    
    CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS bbox_spatial_index ON rm.test USING gist (bbox);
```

Error message is:

> ERROR:  data type box2d has no default operator class for access
> method "gist" HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index
> or define a default operator class for the data type.
>
> SQL state: 42704

Or am I wrong and I should store the bboxes in a different format in a "geometry" column? For example converting them to Polygones or Multipoints?

Versions:

> PostGIS v3.3 (3.3 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1)
>
> PostgreSQL 14.6, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says you can't build a gist index on a box2d. You can make them into polygons and use a gist index or look at different index types but I suspect that those won't really speed things up.